# Was Barry always this version of the Flash?

Tags: the-flash-2014

In the episode *[A New World, Part 1](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/A_New_World,_Part_One)* we see Barry go back to the year 2000, the same year that his Mom died. He encounters 'Reverse Flash' again when he's about to kill Barry as a child.

After one final day with his parents, he goes to face Thawne at his house. He tries to to talk him out of it and then we see him go through what we saw that night and Season 9 Barry become the 'Original Timeline Flash'

[image]
[image]

**Does this mean that the Barry that stopped his Season 1 self from saving his Mom was always our current version (in Season 9)?**